# Potential race condition in the timer class?

Tags: java, multithreading, timer, thread-safety

I have written a timer which will measure the performance of a particular code in any multithreaded application. In the below timer, it will also populate the map with how many calls took x milliseconds. I will use this map as part of my histogram to do further analysis, like what percentage of calls took this much milliseconds and etc.

```
public static class StopWatch {

    public static ConcurrentHashMap<Long, Long> histogram = new ConcurrentHashMap<Long, Long>();

    public static StopWatch getInstance() {
        return new StopWatch();
    }

    private long m_end = -1;
    private long m_interval = -1;
    private final long m_start;

    private StopWatch() {
        m_start = m_interval = currentTime();
    }

    public long getDuration() {
        long result = 0;

        final long startTime = m_start;
        final long endTime = isStopWatchRunning() ? currentTime() : m_end;

        result = convertNanoToMilliseconds(endTime - startTime);

        boolean done = false;
        while (!done) {
            Long oldValue = histogram.putIfAbsent(result, 1L);
            if (oldValue != null) {
                done = histogram.replace(result, oldValue, oldValue + 1);
            } else {
                done = true;
            }
        }

        return result;
    }

    public long getInterval() {
        long result = 0;

        final long startTime = m_interval;
        final long endTime;

        if (isStopWatchRunning()) {
            endTime = m_interval = currentTime();
        } else {
            endTime = m_end;
        }

        result = convertNanoToMilliseconds(endTime - startTime);

        return result;
    }

    public void stop() {
        if (isStopWatchRunning()) {
            m_end = currentTime();
        }
    }

    private long currentTime() {
        return System.nanoTime();
    }

    private boolean isStopWatchRunning() {
        return (m_end <= 0);
    }

    private long convertNanoToMilliseconds(final long nanoseconds) {
        return nanoseconds / 1000000L;
    }
}
```

For example, this is the way I will use my above timer class to measure the performance of a particular code in my multithreading application:

```
StopWatch timer = StopWatch.getInstance();
//... some code here to measure
timer.getDuration();
```

Now my question is - If you look at the `getDuration` method, I am also populating my map with the information like how many calls took x milliseconds so that I can use that map later on for further analysis like calculating average, median, 95th and 99th percentile. Does my below code thread safe or is there any race condition?

```
boolean done = false;
while (!done) {
    Long oldValue = histogram.putIfAbsent(result, 1L);
    if (oldValue != null) {
        done = histogram.replace(result, oldValue, oldValue + 1);
    } else {
        done = true;
    }
}
```

Between the call to `Long oldValue = histogram.putIfAbsent(result, 1L);` and `done = histogram.replace(result, oldValue, oldValue + 1);`, the values in the map could have changed. Thus, `oldValue` could be stale?

Comment: this topic is for http://codereview.stackexchange.com/

Comment: @AlexeiKaigorodov Only if the code is working as intended, of which the OP isn't sure. Broken code is [off-topic](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) at Code Review

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The portion you called out looks correct. Yes sometimes oldValue will be stale, but that's why you're looping. Right?

An alternative approach is to put AtomicLongs into the map. Then you put/get the  AtomicLong and increment that.

```
histogram.putIfAbsent(result, new AtomicLong());
histogram.get(result).incrementAndGet();
```

In java 8 you may be able to use `compute` and friends to your advantage (test and see which you like the best):

```
histogram.computeIfAbsent(result, AtomicLong::new);
histogram.get(result).incrementAndGet();

// or
if (histogram.putIfAbsent(result, new AtomicLong(1)) == null)
   histogram.get(result).incrementAndGet();

// or even
histogram.compute(result, ($, current) -> {
   if (current == null) return new AtomicLong(1);
   current.incrementAndGet();
   return current;
});
```

Comment: Yes and I mean to say is there any alternative way to do this instead of looping as the way I am doing right now?

Comment: `computeIfAbsent` returns the effective value, so it intentionally allows to write the operation as the single statement `histogram.computeIfAbsent(result, AtomicLong::new).incrementAndGet();` without the need for another `get`, read hashing only a single time instead of twice… Even without the `AtomicLong`, the new API allows to optimize the call: `histogram.merge(result, 1L, Long::sum);` which is already an atomic update.